# Output camera frame buffers aren't coming

Tags: ios, swift

I implemented `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate` for a camera class

set needed video input and started a session, camera works ok, can see it on the preview

also I would like to get pixel buffer for some processing

```
fileprivate func configureVideoOutput() {
    let videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
    videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue(label: "sample buffer"))

    if self.session.canAddOutput(videoOutput) {
        print("canAddOutput yes")
        self.session.addOutput(videoOutput)
        print("canAddOutput yes added")
    } else {
        print("canAddOutput no")
    }
}

func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
    print("Got a frame!")
}
```

it prints `"canAddOutput yes added"` ok

but it never prints `"Got a frame!"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must setting the output type first

```
videoOutput.videoSettings = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA]
```

Edit:
Change the delegate function to

```
public func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
   print("Got a frame 1!") 
}
```

Comment: added, but it didn't help

Comment: @user924 You are using Swift 3 or 4, can you recheck your delegate function name `func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection)`

Comment: Thanks. I needed to use `public func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput,
                       didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer,
                       from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        print("Got a frame 1!")
    }`

Answer (score 0):

I can't see if you have started `AVCaptureSession`, by calling `start()`. Next thing, when you set `delegate` to `self` with `setSampleBufferDelegate`, you trying to start recording, but you call it before videoOutput is added you your session, so it can be a problem too.
I have small project on GitHub what demonstrate how to setup custom camera https://github.com/ChernyshenkoTaras/CustomCamera you can use it as example

Comment: do you mean `.startRunning()`? I did this, I wouldn't see any video stream in my preview if I didn't do it

Comment: I moved `setSampleBufferDelegate` after `videoOutput` adding to session, but it didn't help

Comment: Probably it can be because you have local variable `videoOutput ` and it release after `configureVideoOutput ` is executed. Try to store it as a property